# Exclude subspecs from podspec with Jazzy swift documentation generation

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, jazzy

I'm currently developing an iOS SDK using Cocoapods to manage deployment and Jazzy to generate documentation. I recently added a dependency to Google ads v8 in a subspec, and another dependency to Google ads v7 in another subspec, like this:

```
  s.subspec 'Admob' do |admob|
    admob.source_files = 'MyLib/Classes/admob/**/*.{swift,h,m}'
    admob.dependency 'MyLib/Core'
    admob.dependency 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 8.0'
    admob.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS' => '$(inherited) -D SDK_ADMOB' }
  end

  s.subspec 'Admob7' do |admob|
    admob.source_files = 'MyLib/Classes/admob7/**/*.{swift,h,m}'
    admob.dependency 'MyLib/Core'
    admob.dependency 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
    admob.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS' => '$(inherited) -D SDK_ADMOB' }
    admob.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
    admob.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  end
```

Everything is working fine, except when I want to generate doc with Jazzy. Here is my conf:

```
documentation: "*.md"
xcodebuild_arguments: -scheme,Tests
module: MyLib
sdk: iphone
source_directory: MyLib
podspec: MyLib.podspec
theme: fullwidth
readme: USERGUIDE.md
```

when I run `bundle exec jazzy` I have a conflict because it wants tu use all my subspecs at the same time:

```
Using config file /Users/***/***/.jazzy.yaml
Analyzing dependencies
bundler: failed to load command: jazzy (/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/jazzy)
Pod::Informative: [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK":
  In Podfile:
    MyLib/Admob (from `/Users/***/***`) was resolved to 2.8.0, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 8.0)

    MyLib/Admob7 (from `/Users/***/***`) was resolved to 2.8.0, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.0)
```

Can somebody tell me if it's possible to exclude one or several subspecs from my doc generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it appears that there are no options in Jazzy to overcome this issue. I ended up writing this script:

```sh
### Removing admob7 subspec before generating doc is necessary.
# add a new line to the podspec file to remove it after awk treatment
echo "" >> MyLib.podspec

# create the jazzy podspec
awk '!/Admob7/' RS=s.subspec ORS=s.subspec MyLib.podspec > MyLib.jazzy.podspec

# clean the last line which contains an awk artifact
sed -i '' -e '$ d' MyLib.jazzy.podspec

# remove the last line we added before
sed -i '' -e '$ d' MyLib.podspec

bundle exec jazzy
```

And changed the podspec in the jazzy yml config file

```yaml
documentation: "*.md"
xcodebuild_arguments: -scheme,Tests
module: MyLib
sdk: iphone
source_directory: MyLib
podspec: MyLib.jazzy.podspec
theme: fullwidth
readme: USERGUIDE.md
```